# Using the MIDI tick position to control movement of a graphic marker in a sequence

Tags: java, swing, midi, javasound

I'm trying to assemble a graphical representation of a MIDI sequence, and I'd like a vertical line to move across the panel horizontally as the sequence plays, reflecting the actual position in the sequence.  I know that I should use something like `getTickPosition()` to provide the location of the vertical line.

But how do I fire off these events so that the vertical line knows to redraw itself?  Do I create a special listener that the ticks somehow trigger?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Establish a Swing `Timer` to check and update the tick position every NN milliseconds.

> So, there's not any kind of built-in timer in the MidiSystem?

Sure there is.  But the point is that all GUI updates should happen on the EDT.  By invoking them from a Swing `Timer`, they are.  Also, the MIDI timer is for the use of MIDI API/System, let it do what it does undisturbed, and report back the relevant information when checked from the Swing `Timer`.

Also, given the nature of the UI component, look to a `JProgressBar` as seen in the upper right of this GUI.

[image: DukeBox GUI]

### Update

I adapted the source seen on the [Java Sound WIKI](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info) into an SSCCE of this approach.

[image: Play MIDI showing progress]

```
import javax.sound.midi.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.net.URL;

class PlayMidi {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL("http://pscode.org/media/EverLove.mid");
        Sequence sequence = MidiSystem.getSequence(url);
        final Sequencer sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
        sequencer.open();
        sequencer.setSequence(sequence);
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                final JProgressBar progress = new JProgressBar(0,(int)sequencer.getMicrosecondLength()); 
                ActionListener updateListener = new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                        progress.setValue((int)sequencer.getMicrosecondPosition());
                    }
                };
                Timer timer = new Timer(40,updateListener); 
                sequencer.start();
                timer.start();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, progress);
                sequencer.close();
                timer.stop();
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew.  So, there's not any kind of built-in timer in the MidiSystem?  I'm being told that there is, but I can't find it mentioned in any of the documentation.

Comment: Makes total sense.  I'll try this out (hopefully in the morning) and see if I can get it working, and I'll report back. Thanks!

Comment: Start with the latest source added to the question (but turn the volume way down first - it is a very loud track!).

Comment: This is a piano roll editor. The vertical line will be a playbar that scrolls across a grid as the sequence plays. I can't really use a progress bar, but I can take your idea: I start a Timer when the user presses Play. The timer fires events every _ milliseconds which check for the tick position. The panel redraws playbar based on tick position. Create a Playbar class within panel that extends Line2D and implements ActionListener & Runnable.  Put timer and action event both within the run method.  I guess I'll call the Playbar class's constructor from within the panel's paintComponent method?

Comment: OK Andrew.  I read your directions for trimming it down to make it SSCCE, and I've got a LOT of trimming to do if I'm going to post it here.  Let me mess with the problem a little tonight and see if I can figure my way based on what you've already given me.  If I can't, I'll see if I can extract the essential code and paste it here.  Thank you VERY much for your time.  This is my first project that's not an exercise in a book, so the help on this forum is like gold to me. :-)

Comment: I did it!  Holy cow!  I have to tweak the numbers to get the playbar to line up with notes drawn on the screen, but that'll be the easy part.  Getting to this point was like climbing Everest for me!  Thanks Andrew.  I'd love to post this code so that it will be helpful for others, but it's spread across three different .java files.  Is it OK to post snippets, or does it have to be compilable?

Comment: *"I'd love to post this code so that it will be helpful for others,"* Github or Sourceforge is a better place for share code.  OTOH, you can sometimes sneak it into codereview.stackexchange.com, like [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4446/file-browser-gui).  ;)  Glad you got it sorted.  :)

Answer (score 1):

I would take a close look at the following tutorial.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/MIDI-seq-adv.html

There are a couple different things that may be of use: tools for synchronizing with other devices and special event listeners. The following (about the *slave*) looks particularly promising:

> Sequencer has an inner class called Sequencer.SyncMode. A SyncMode object represents one of the ways in which a MIDI sequencer's notion of time can be synchronized with a master or slave device. If the sequencer is being synchronized to a master, the sequencer revises its current time in response to certain MIDI messages from the master. If the sequencer has a slave, the sequencer similarly sends MIDI messages to control the slave's timing.

If you write a "MidiSlaveDevice" that's sole job is to send triggers to your redraw, you could have the solution to your desired scenario. Mind you, I haven't done this myself yet, so I'm not entirely sure it works.

Comment: Thanks Phil.  That's definitely thinking outside the box!